# Jquery selecting divs based on their id number

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am discovering JQuery and can't find an answer to my question, after a lot of research, because I don't know how to express it well.

I have 2 rulers + 2 guides on my page and 2 buttons to show or hide them.
I wrote something that works but I would like to optimize the code by making it shorter.

Here it is:

```
$('#ruler-bg1, #ruler-bg2').hide();

$('#ruler1').click(function() {
  $('#ruler-bg1').slideToggle(100);
  $('#guide1').toggleClass('guide-on');
});

$('#ruler2').click(function() {
  $('#ruler-bg2').slideToggle(100);
  $('#guide2').toggleClass('guide-on');
});
```

What I can't figure out is how to group the 2 functions so a click on `#ruler+number` shows `#ruler-bg+same_number` and `#guide+same_number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
$('#ruler1, #ruler2').click(function(){
    var num = this.id.substr(6);

    $('#ruler-bg' + num).slideToggle(100);
    $('#guide' + num).toggleClass('guide-on');
});
```

It would probably be nicer if there was some structural relationship between the element clicked and the elements acted upon...

Comment: hmmm, works in this case, although won't scale well for larger index values, while a little slower, maybe a regular expression is more maintainable/scalable.

Comment: @davin What do you mean, "larger index values"? If there are more `ruler#` elements, it would be best to give them a class as well as an id and use a class selector.

Comment: If there are indexes above 10, the `substr` will think 11 and 1 are equivalent: `"#ruler11".substr(-1) === "#ruler1".substr(-1)` And while you could `substr` from the beginning of the string using the length of `"#ruler"`, again, that isn't as scalable as a regular expression

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I'd like to understand the code, what does this mean please: `var num = this.id.substr(-1);`?

Comment: @davin A regular expression here would be overkill, and no more reliable than removing the first 6 characters. I've changed it to that approach, though, as your point is valid.

Comment: @user495915 It means take a substring from the ID starting one character before the end. `substr(6)` (see my edited answer) means "starting six characters from the beginning. [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class "ruler" to all the "rulers" and use the id´s as identifier on the ruler-bg and guide.

```
$('.ruler').click(function(){
    $('#bg-'+this.id).slideToggle(100);
    $('#guide-'+this.id).toggleClass('guide-on');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
initRuler(1);
initRuler(2);

function initRuler(id) {
  $('#ruler' + id).click(function() {
    $('#ruler-bg' + id).slideToggle(100);
    $('#guide' + id).toggleClass('guide-on');
  });
}
```