# Jquery - Help Loop Script

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a script that needs to be repeated 12 times. Below is the script that is ran twice. I do not want to repeat this twelve times. This is an checkbox onclick checkbox. Is there an easier way for me to repeat this other then copying and pasting enable 1 through 12.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function($) {   
  $('.rowhid,.rowhid2').hide();
  $("input[name='enable']").click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var remove = '';
      $('.rowhid').hide();
    } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
      $('.rowhid').show();
    }
  });
  $("input[name='enable2']").click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var remove = '';
      $('.rowhid2').hide();
    } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
      $('.rowhid2').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have improved your code formatting - it helps a lot.  Think loops, think string concatonation...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think loops, think string concatenation:

E.g (though not 100% what you're looking for)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {

        var elementId = '.rowhid'+i;

        $(elementId).hide();

        $("input[name='enable']").click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              var remove = '';
              $(elementId).hide();
            }
            else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
              $(elementId).show();
            }
         });
    }
});
```

Making it exactly what you need is left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 1):

If you rename the `.rowhid` to `.rowhid1`, and `enable` to `enable1`, you can do this easily with a `for` loop. Like shown in the solution below:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {   
$('.rowhid,.rowhid2').hide();

for (var i=1; i<=12; i++)

{   

    $("input[name='enable"+i+"']").click(function(){

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        var remove = '';

        $('.rowhid'+i).hide();}

    else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {$('.rowhid'+i).show();}

    });  

}  


});
```

#### Better alternative:

For a nicer solution without a `for` loop, you can look at the answers to the following question:
[Jquery selecting divs based on their id number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448489/jquery-selecting-divs-based-on-their-id-number)

Comment: This nearly worked but some reason the second half didn't want to work.

Comment: What is the second half?

Comment: $('.rowhid'+i).hide();}

    else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {$('.rowhid'+i).show();}


when i click the check box it does not trigger. IF i take +i out and just use .rowhid1 the script works but not what we want to do. I did rename the triger to enable1 and rowhid1 to the table row.